# wget page and insert source domain

Tags: wget

I'm attempting to create a short script to cache a dynamically generated web page on another server.

I only want the one page so using

```
wget http://domain/file
```

Could be enough but the file contains relative links, which arent valid on the host.

Any ideas of an easy way to replace the relative links with absolute ones pointing to the original server/domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `-k` option:

> - Downloaded files will be changed to refer to the file they point to as a relative link.
> - Not downloaded files will be changed to include host name and absolute path of the location they point to.